# PowerShell - server local admins reporting from a list of servers

Tags: powershell

Beginner question. We only grant access to servers by AD group. We need to report who has admin access to a list of Windows servers. My auditor likes my Server Admins script however she also wants to know the group members first, last name. I don't need to use the ADGroupMember script, if there is a better way.

If someone could point me in the right direction that will be great. It's important I understand so I can do it myself next time : )

Thanks in advance

```
$computers = Get-content "c:\scripts\servers.txt"
ForEach ($Line In $computers)

{
  #write-host $Line
 Invoke-command -ComputerName $line -ScriptBlock { net localgroup administrators}  | Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "$_????what goes here????" |%{get-aduser $_.SamAccountName | select userPrincipalName } | out-file "c:\scripts\'$line'LocalAdmin.txt"
 }
```

This script works great but does not list out group members first, lastname

```
$computers = Get-content "c:\scripts\servers.txt"
ForEach ($Line In $computers)

{
  #write-host $Line
 Invoke-command -ComputerName $line -ScriptBlock { net localgroup administrators}  | out-file "c:\scripts\'$line'LocalAdmin.txt"
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really need information about the users in the *local* `Administrators` group, you can use the cmdlets from the PSv5.1+ [`Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts) module.

However, note that local accounts just have a single `.FullName` property, not separate first and last name ones. Also, this property may or may not be filled in:

```sh
Invoke-Command -ComputerName (Get-Content c:\scripts\servers.txt) -ScriptBlock {
  Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators | 
    Where-Object ObjectClass -eq User |
      Select-Object Sid | 
        Get-LocalUser
} |
  Sort-Object PSComputerName | 
    Select-Object PSComputerName, Name, FullName
```

If domain users are among the group's members and you do need separate first and last name information, pipe to `Get-ADUser` instead of to `Get-LocalUser` - you can distinguish users by their source (where they are defined) via the `.PrincipalSource` property, available on the output objects from `Get-LocalGroupMember` from Window 10 / Windows Server 2016.

Comment: Thanks mklement0. Your script looks good however it complains I don't have WS-Management service running on the destination servers. I don't see that service so I need to figure this one out. I'll let you know

Comment: @tux, the name of the WS-Management service is `WinRM` - but note that if it isn't running on a given machine, you won't be able to connect to it via PowerShell remoting (`Invoke-Command -ComputerName ...`) at all. Are some of the computers not set up for PowerShell remoting?

Comment: Thanks mklement0. I believe WinRm is enabled. I'm working with another guy at my company, he has been using the Invoke-Command. I will get back with you what we find. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to [mklement0's helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70296841/15339544) answer, somewhat old school, using `[adsi]`:

```
$servers = Get-Content c:\scripts\servers.txt

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers -ScriptBlock {
    $adsi = [adsi]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME,computer"
    $adsi.PSBase.Children.Find('Administrators').PSBase.Invoke('members') |
    ForEach-Object {
        $Name    = $_.GetType().InvokeMember('Name','GetProperty',$null,$_,$null)
        $class   = $_.GetType().InvokeMember('Class','GetProperty',$null,$_,$null)
        $adspath = $_.GetType().InvokeMember('ADSPath','GetProperty',$null,$_,$null)
        $sid = [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new(
            $_.GetType().InvokeMember('objectsid','GetProperty',$null,$_,$null),0
        ).Value
    
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Name = $Name
            Class = $Class
            Path = $adspath -replace '^WinNT://'
            SecurityIdentifier = $sid
        }
    } | Sort-Object Class -Descending
} | Where-Object Class -EQ User
```

Comment: Thanks Santiago. Your script runs without error. How do I see the output? I would like to see each server report in its own txt report.                                                                          ty